# Cassandra Topology issue

Tags: cassandra

I have configured cassandra 3.0.9 on our 3 nodes where 2 nodes are in same data center while 1 is in different data center. each data center is having a seed node but when 1 seed node goes down application not getting any data from the database is there any specific thing to do in configuration part of data base? please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to check your consistency level for cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure same seed node on all the available nodes.

> Application not getting any data

This depends on the CONSISTENCY used to query the database.

Comment: seed node configured for all available nodes but when seed node goes down application should get the data from rest of the nodes instead of that application stops working.